# How to actually use Q promise in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

This might be a noob question, but I'm new to promises and trying to figure out how to use [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) in node.js.

I see the [tutorial](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#tutorial) begins with a

```
promiseMeSomething()
    .then(function (value) {}, function (reason) {});
```

but I fail to grasp where exactly does the `.then` came from. I guess it comes from

```
var outputPromise = getInputPromise()
    .then(function (input) {}, function (reason) {});
```

but where does `getInputPromise()` come from? I find no previous mention of it.

---

I have included it in my project like so

```
var Q = require('q');

// this is suppose, the async function I want to use promise for
function async(cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        cb();
    }, 5000);
}

async(function () {
    console.log('async called back');
});
```

How do I use `Q` and its `.then` here in my example?

Comment: Your example isn't a great use case for promises. The `then` function is attached to promises, and yes, something needs to create that promise. Sometimes libraries do. It's a MySQL-related example, but you might find helpful [an answer I gave someone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109487/nodejs-mysql-dump/22110015#22110015) in which I implement the answer using normal callbacks and then using Q promises, with heavy commenting on the Q part illustrating what is going on.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545087/how-to-use-q-module-for-refactoring-mongoose-code

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`promiseMeSomething()` is going to return a Q promise object, which will have `then` function in it, which is [defined](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L779), like this

```
Promise.prototype.then = function (fulfilled, rejected, progressed) {
```

The simplest way to create a Promise object would be to use the `Q` function constructor, like this

```
new Q(value)
```

will create a new promise object. You can then attach the success and failure handlers, like this

```
new Q(value)
.then(function(/*Success handler*/){}, function(/*Failure handler*/){})
```

Moreover, if you pass a single nodejs-style function to `.then` function, it will call that function with the success value like this

```
callback(null, value)
```

or if there is a problem, then

```
callback(error)
```

For your particular case, `setTimeout` accepts the function to be called as the first parameter. So, it would take quite few lines of code to make it really work with promises. So, `Q` has a convenient function, for this purpose, [`Q.delay`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdelayms), which can be used like this

```
var Q = require('q');

function async() {
    return Q.delay(1000)
}

async()
.then(function() {
    console.log('async called back');
});
```

You can write it shorter like this

```
Q.delay(1000)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('async called back');
    });
```

If you wanted to call the callback function with someother value, then you can do it like this

```
Q.delay(1000, "Success")
    .then(function(value) {
        console.log('async called back with', value);
    });
```

This is going to be useful, when you want to have a delay between two functions and the second function is dependent on the first function.